# Issue with mongoId's any_of implementation for activerecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, mongoid

I have my settings model's data like this

```
[52] pry(main)> Setting.all.to_a
    => [#<Setting _id: 561cc75b25917fdc2300003c, courses: ["521c4578ef8b6038ba000069", "55f909c825917f1ac000003e"], user_id: "55f908d725917f5157000036">,
     #<Setting _id: 563b322425917f8117000025, courses: ["561cddbb25917fa26e0000b9", "5614e62225917fbb1300005f", "5617a6bd25917f7aa100005d", "560ca6b325917f158d000002", "5617a5f325917ff38c000036", "5632eebc25917f1ace000038", "55f909c825917f1ac000003e", "521c4578ef8b6038ba000069"], user_id: "56125d7b25917fb8c0000001">,
     #<Setting _id: 5641d3b125917fa02f000009, courses: ["5614e62225917fbb1300005f", "55f909c825917f1ac000003e", "521c4578ef8b6038ba000069"], user_id: "5264b629ef8b604f96000001">,
     #<Setting _id: 565d541925917f10da000013, courses: ["561cddbb25917fa26e0000b9", "5614e62225917fbb1300005f", "5617a6bd25917f7aa100005d", "5617a5f325917ff38c000036", "560ca6b325917f158d000002", "55f909c825917f1ac000003e", "5632eebc25917f1ace000038", "521c4578ef8b6038ba000069"], user_id: "565d53f525917f10da000012">]
```

Now i want array of settings which has particular course

```
    pry(main)> course = Course.find("5614e62225917fbb1300005f")
    pry(main)> Setting.any_of(courses: course.id).to_a
=> [#<Setting _id: 565d541925917f10da000013, courses: ["561cddbb25917fa26e0000b9", "5614e62225917fbb1300005f", "5617a6bd25917f7aa100005d", "5617a5f325917ff38c000036", "560ca6b325917f158d000002", "55f909c825917f1ac000003e", "5632eebc25917f1ace000038", "521c4578ef8b6038ba000069"], user_id: "565d53f525917f10da000012">]
```

It yielded just one array element which is not the desired result, then

```
[53] pry(main)> Setting.any_of(courses: course.id.to_s).to_a
=> [#<Setting _id: 563b322425917f8117000025, courses: ["561cddbb25917fa26e0000b9", "5614e62225917fbb1300005f", "5617a6bd25917f7aa100005d", "560ca6b325917f158d000002", "5617a5f325917ff38c000036", "5632eebc25917f1ace000038", "55f909c825917f1ac000003e", "521c4578ef8b6038ba000069"], user_id: "56125d7b25917fb8c0000001">,
 #<Setting _id: 5641d3b125917fa02f000009, courses: ["5614e62225917fbb1300005f", "55f909c825917f1ac000003e", "521c4578ef8b6038ba000069"], user_id: "5264b629ef8b604f96000001">]
```

Yielded two array element but the desired result is three array element which  can be attained by adding these two results or by following syntax

```
[57] pry(main)> Setting.any_of({courses: course.id.to_s}, {courses: course.id}).to_a
=> [#<Setting _id: 563b322425917f8117000025, courses: ["561cddbb25917fa26e0000b9", "5614e62225917fbb1300005f", "5617a6bd25917f7aa100005d", "560ca6b325917f158d000002", "5617a5f325917ff38c000036", "5632eebc25917f1ace000038", "55f909c825917f1ac000003e", "521c4578ef8b6038ba000069"], user_id: "56125d7b25917fb8c0000001">,
 #<Setting _id: 5641d3b125917fa02f000009, courses: ["5614e62225917fbb1300005f", "55f909c825917f1ac000003e", "521c4578ef8b6038ba000069"], user_id: "5264b629ef8b604f96000001">,
 #<Setting _id: 565d541925917f10da000013, courses: ["561cddbb25917fa26e0000b9", "5614e62225917fbb1300005f", "5617a6bd25917f7aa100005d", "5617a5f325917ff38c000036", "560ca6b325917f158d000002", "55f909c825917f1ac000003e", "5632eebc25917f1ace000038", "521c4578ef8b6038ba000069"], user_id: "565d53f525917f10da000012">]
```

My confusion is why does

```
Setting.any_of(courses: course.id).to_a
```

and

```
Setting.any_of(courses: course.id.to_s).to_a
```

yields different results and is my third syntax approach the only correct way to attain the result i want ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't be 100% sure since I don't really know what's inside your database. However, I'm pretty confident about the issue here.

Since you didn't share your Setting model definition, I'd guess it's something along these lines:

```
class Setting
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :courses, type: Array
end
```

If this is not correct, please let me know and I'll update the answer. Given that structure, look at this pry session:

```
[4] pry(main)> string_id = "563b322425917f8117000025"   
=> "563b322425917f8117000025"
[5] pry(main)> object_id = Moped::BSON::ObjectId.from_string("563b322425917f8117000025")   
=> "563b322425917f8117000025"
[6] pry(main)> string_id.class.name   
=> "String"
[7] pry(main)> object_id.class.name   
=> "Moped::BSON::ObjectId"
```

Please note that `Moped::BSON::ObjectId` applies to Mongoid 3 (the one I happen to have installed here). In newer versions it's simply `BSON::ObjectId`, as Mongoid 4+ abandoned the Moped gem.

We can create two different objects to represent the same identifier. One is a String instance, the other one is of class Moped::BSON::ObjectId, used internally by Mongoid to represent the same thing, i.e., a Mongo ObejctId.

To make thing easier, Mongoid (and mongo itself) allow you in some contexts to use Strings instead of ObjectIds, but not always. In some contexts, as of the above Setting class, it cannot know if you want to save a String instance or an ObjectId instance to the database. So, it will save whatever you send it to:

```
[10] pry(main)> st = Setting.new(:courses => [object_id])
=> #<Setting _id: 5694ff9a04572eeb16000001, courses: ["563b322425917f8117000025"]>
[11] pry(main)> st.save
=> true
[12] pry(main)> st2 = Setting.new(:courses => [string_id])
=> #<Setting _id: 5694ffa904572eeb16000002, courses: ["563b322425917f8117000025"]>
[13] pry(main)> st2.save
=> true
[14] pry(main)> Setting.where(:courses => string_id).to_a
=> [#<Setting _id: 5694ffa904572eeb16000002, courses: ["563b322425917f8117000025"]>]
[15] pry(main)> Setting.where(:courses => string_id).to_a == [st2]
=> true
[17] pry(main)> Setting.where(:courses => object_id).to_a == [st]
=> true
```

So, the variable `st` points to a `Setting` object saved with a courses field containing one single id, represented as an `Moped::BSON::ObjectId` instance, while `st2` contains a plain String representation of the same id. So, those two things look the same, and it's hard to spot because `Moped::BSON::ObjectID#to_s` method returns exactly the same id as `String#to_s`, so if you try to print it into a shell session you won't be able to spot the difference. To spot the difference you have to call `object_id.class.name` and compare with `string_id.class.name`.

You can prove if that is your case, by running this:

```
all_settings = Setting.any_of({courses: course.id.to_s}, {courses: course.id})
all_settings.each do |a_setting|
  puts "Setting #{a_setting.id}:"

  a_setting.courses.each do |string_or_object_id|
    puts "   #{string_or_object_id.class.name} #{string_or_object_id}"
  end
end
```

Ideally you should use either only String objects or only ObjectId objects inside this array, otherwise you **will have future** problems. To fix this. I'd suggest you use `Moped::BSON::ObjectId`, as it maps to the natural ObjectId Mongo representation and allows you to do some interesting things, as querying an ObjectId by it's generation date:

```
[21] pry(main)> object_id.generation_time
=> 2015-11-05 10:40:36 UTC
```

I hope this helps :)

Comment: I'd also recommend including a `before_validation` hook to convert all the entries in `courses` to ObjectIds and a validation to make sure they really are all ObjectIds. Sooner or later something will put a string in there.

Comment: Thank you so much for such clear explanation , solved my issue converting string to ObjectId each time the Setting is updated
Moped::BSON::ObjectId.from_string(course_id)

Thanks for the heads-up  @muistooshort